# Differentiation dr/dx in cylindrical coordinates from cartesian

Tags: calculus

For transformation from cartesian to cylindrical coordinates,

$$
\ x=r~cos \theta ,~~ y=r~ sin \theta , ~~ r=(x^2+y^2)^{1/2} 
$$
Then, 
$$
\frac {dr} {dx} =\frac {1} {2} (x^2+y^2)^{-1/2}~2x~=~\frac {x} {(x^2+y^2)^{1/2} }~=~\frac {r~cos \theta} {r}~=~ cos \theta
$$
Is it possible to obtain the same result by differentiating the below relationship?
$$
r~=~\frac {x} {cos \theta}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hint
use quotient rule:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind and fast answer. Yes. I do get the same answer!! You helped me a lot!!!

Comment: @tony - You are welcome